# Sampling groups in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Say I want to do a **stratified** sample from a dataframe in Pandas so that I get `5%` of rows for every value of a given column. How can I do that?

For example, in the dataframe below, I would like to sample `5%` of the rows associated with each value of the column `Z`. Is there any way to **sample groups** from a dataframe loaded in memory?

```
> df 

   X   Y  Z
   1 123  a
   2  89  b
   1 234  a
   4 893  a
   6 234  b
   2 893  b
   3 200  c
   5 583  c
   2 583  c
   6 100  c
```

More generally, what if I this dataframe in disk in a huge file (e.g. 8 GB of a csv file). Is there any way to do this sampling without having to load the entire dataframe in memory?

Comment: You could count the number of lines in the csv and then `read_csv` and set `nrows` to the `number of lines/20`

Comment: Thanks @EdChum but that would not return a stratified sample.

Comment: Hmm. you'd probably have to store this in pytables or hdf5 and then run a query, not sure how else to do this without loading into a dataframe. The other way is to use the `chunksize` param which returns a `TextFileRader` and query if the row is of interest and if not skip but this would be very slow potentially

Comment: The biggest issue is that there is no way to know that you've hit the 5% mark until you've read the entire file. It would be more feasible to request the "first 10 instances" because we can stop recording a specific `Z` instance after a while. But a percentage cut-off means we have to count everything.

Comment: @chrisaycock I would imagine one could technically "grep" the file to do the count first (i.e. without loading the file in memory) and then sample accordingly?

Comment: Would you need the rows to be taken randomly, or are they already sufficiently random? Meaning, you could take the first 5% of a's that occur?

Comment: @DataSwede sampling in order would be enough! (I can always shuffle lines prior to the sampling using command line tools)

Comment: Using the options skiprows and nrows you can break up the read_csv into chunks you can fit into working memory.

Answer (score 4):

How about loading only the 'Z' column into memory using the 'usecols' option. Say the file is sample.csv. That should use much less memory if you have a bunch of columns. Then assuming that fits into memory, I think this will work for you.

```
stratfraction = 0.05
#Load only the Z column
df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv', usecols = ['Z'])
#Generate the counts per value of Z
df['Obs']  = 1
gp = df.groupby('Z')
#Get number of samples per group 
df2 = np.ceil(gp.count()*stratfraction)
#Generate the indices of the request sample (first entrie)
stratsample = []
for i, key in enumerate(gp.groups):
    FirstFracEntries = gp.groups[key][0:int(df2['Obs'][i])]
    stratsample.extend(FirstFracEntries) 
#Generate a list of rows to skip since read_csv doesn't have a rows to keep option
stratsample.sort
RowsToSkip = set(df.index.values).difference(stratsample)
#Load only the requested rows (no idea how well this works for a really giant list though)         
df3 = df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv', skiprows  = RowsToSkip)
```