# Convient way for sample chunks in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have data that tracks a group of individuals over time. To give a small example it looks kind of like this:

```
ID    TIME   HEIGHT
0     0      10.2
0     1      3.3
0     2      2.1
1     0      11.3
1     1      8.6
1     2      9.1
2     0      10.0
2     1      35.0
2     2      4.1
.
.
.
100   0      1.0
100   1      3.0
100   2      9.0
```

Where, for illustration, `ID` refers to a particular person. Thus, this plotting `TIME` on the x-axis and `HEIGHT` on the y-axis for all the values of `ID=0` gives us the change in person `0`s height.

I want to graph a random sample of these people and plot them. So for instance, I want to plot the change in height over time of 3 people. However, applying the usual `df.sample(3)` will not always ensure that I get all of the time for a particular person, instead it will select randomly 3 rows and plot them. Is there a preferred/convenient way in `pandas` to sample random groups?

A lot of questions like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25203883/sampling-groups-in-pandas) seem to be about sampling from every group which is not what I want to do.

Comment: `df.groupby('ID')` would be a good start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to plot `'TIME'` in the x-axis, then get a rectangular dataframe with `'TIME'` as the index and `'ID'` as the columns.  From there, use `sample` with `axis=1` to sample columns and leave the index intact.

```
df.set_index(['TIME', 'ID']).HEIGHT.unstack().sample(3, axis=1).plot()
```

[image]